# Prove that i^2 = -1

Tags: real-analysis, complex-numbers

From Rudin's principle of mathematical analysis (3rd edition)

"
1.28 Theorem
$i^2 = -1$

Proof
$i^2 = (0,1)(0,1) = (-1,0) = -1$
"

Why is (0,1)(0,1) = (-1,0). What math am I missing here.

Comment: how do you prove $i^2=-1$ isn't that the definition lol

Comment: Edit: See definition 1.24.

Comment: It is common to define $i=(0,1)$, and then $i^2=-1$ is a theorem you can prove using the definition of complex multiplication.

Comment: Presumably $(a,b)(c,d)$ is defined to be $(ac - bd, ad + bc)$ somewhere prior to this theorem. This is the definition of multiplication in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Wgrenard.  It is the definition 1.24 (pg 12).  The complex numbers are the set of ordered real number pairs with the arithmatic defined as you put it.

Comment: Saket malyala.   Not in this text.  i is simply defined to be the ordered pair (0,1).  Nothing more.  Addition and multiplication are defined to be (x,y)+(z,w)=(x+z,y+w) and (x,y). (w,z)=(xw-yz,xz+yw).  With those definitions (0,1)(0,1)=(-1,0)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Multiplication for the complex field is defined as follows:

$x=(a,b), y=(c,d)$

$$xy=(ac-bd, ad+bc)$$

Can you complete the proof?

Comment: Yes I can finish the proof, I didn't think I had to use the previous definition on this one. I thought I had a gap in knowledge somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You can define complex numbers by taking pairs of real numbers $(a,b)$ and defining the usual operations $ + $ and $ * $. However, the definition for multiplication is not as intuitive as it is for sumation. For we have, if:
$$z=(a,b)$$
$$w=(c,d)$$
Then 
$$z*w = (ac-bd,ad+bc)$$
One can check the reason for this definition by using the common notation $ z= a+bi$ and $w=c+di$ , so $zw = (a+bi)(c+di)$ and multiplying algebraically we get:
$$zw = ac-bd + (ad+bc)i$$
Note that here we are using $i^2 = -1$ Which is what we *would* need with our definition.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define what everything *means* first.  And that depends on what text you use.

Now I always keep a copy of Rudin next to my bed....

He does.  1.24 Abstract definition:  A complex number is simply *defined* to be an ordered pair of real numbers.  (x,y) is a "complex number".  Right now it has *nothing* to do with numbers as we know them.

Also as part of the definition he defines what multiplication and addition on them work.

(a,b)+(c,d)= (a+b,c+d)

And

(a,c). (b,d)=(ac-bd,ad+bd)

Okay... let's step away from Rudin and think of these as ordered pairs.

Notice :

(0,1). (0,1)=(0.0-1.1,0.1+1.0)=(-1,0)

That's interesting.  Or not.

Back to rudin.  Th. 1.25 is that this ordered pair or "complex numbers" is a field if we define $(0,0)=0_F $ is the additive identity or "zero" and $(1,0)=1_F $ is the "one" element or the multiplicative identity.

Def: 1.27 is really just a change in notation.  If $(0,0)=0_F$ and $(1,0)=1_F) $ then if we just make up the notation $i_F=(0,1) $ we have a more convenient notation.  Instead of writing an ordered pair as $(a,c) $ we can write it as $(a,c)=(a,0)+(0,c)=(a,0)(1,0)+(c,0)(0,1)=(a,0)1_F+(c,0)i_F $ which we can write with the notation $a_F+c_Fi_F:= (a,c) $.

Now remember that these are simply ordered pars with an arithmetic defined on them.

So th: 1.28.  $i_F^2=-1_F $.

We've already proved this but let's do it again.

$i_F^2=(0,1)*(0,1)=(0*0-1*1,0*1+1*0)=(-1,0)=-1_F $

That's the proof.  This has been about a field of ordered pairs.

Now comes the leap of equivalence:

The set $\mathcal R=\{(x,0)\}\approx \mathbb R$.  That is everything we do on $\mathcal R$ is equivalent to doing the equivalent thing on $\mathbb R$.

So the field of complex numbers $a+ci=(a,c) $ extends the real numbers to the complex numbers where $i^2=(0,1)^2=(-1,0)=-1$.